# how to change width inside jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the following code to change the height of an area but unable to do so inside jquery while apply scrolltop condition please help me where i am wrong ?

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $("#logoin").css("height", "65px");
    }
});
```

my html code is

```
<div  style="position:fixed;width:1348px;height:75px;background-color:Black;opacity:0.7;z-index:200"id="logoin"></div>
```

Comment: You have given 2 Ids to the  same div.

Comment: you assigned the `id` twice

Comment: Html elements should only have one `id`, also if you want your code to work, in your jquery snippet use the `logo` id, as only the first id is taken and later occurrence aren't taken into consideration.

Comment: you want to change width or height?

Comment: i want to change height

Answer (score 2):

Remove `id="logo"` from your `div`